# How to set the time of the progressdialog

Tags: java

```java
public void register() {
        ProjectUtils.showProgressDialog(mContext, true, getResources().getString(R.string.please_waits));
        Log.e("Flag", "Register Click");
        new HttpsRequest(Consts.REGISTER_API, getparm(), mContext).stringPost(tAG, new Helper() {
            @Override
            public void backResponse(boolean flag, String msg, JSONObject response) {
                Log.e("sign", "RESPONSE " + response.toString());
                Log.e("Flag", "FLAG" + flag);
                ProjectUtils.pauseProgressDialog();
                if (flag) {
                    try {
                        ProjectUtils.showToast(mContext, msg);

                        startActivity(new Intent(mContext, SignInActivity.class));
                        finish();
                        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_slide_in_left,
                                R.anim.anim_slide_out_left);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } else {
                    ProjectUtils.showToast(mContext, msg);
                }


            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. I helped you to format the code - supposed it's Java. Otherwise please add the respective language tag. Can you describe your question a bit more, because the method `ProjectUtils.showProgressDialog` is unclear.

Comment: Hi, thanks! Im new on android studio java codes, Im tring to set the progressbar msg to 4 secounds, I will put the rest of the code.... Thanks a lot.

Comment: You'll need to put some text too. What is the context of your Question. What is the issue? This needs to be in the post, not in comments.

Comment: Thanks for try to help me out... Im really beginner in here and android studio as wll, its difficult to ask a question here! im sorry, Im gonna try again! Thanks